# Testing for mod_rewrite on fastcgi?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I am trying to figure out if mod_rewrite is available, based on a couple of snippets from around this very site:

```
$mod_rewrite = null;
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) {
    $mod_rewrite = in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
}
if (is_null($mod_rewrite) && isset($_SERVER["HTTP_MOD_REWRITE"])){
    $mod_rewrite = getenv('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE') == 'on' ? true : false ;
}
if (is_null($mod_rewrite)) {
    ob_start();
    phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if(strpos('_'.$contents, 'mod_rewrite') > 0) {
        $mod_rewrite = true;
    }
}
if (is_null($mod_rewrite)) {
    $result = file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].FB_BASE."/asdfasdf/");
    if (substr($result,0,14) === "<!DOCTYPE HTML>") $mod_rewrite = true;
}
```

Apart from this I have this in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE off
</IfModule>`
```

So in a PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14, CGI/FastCGI environment $mod_rewrite still is null, although it is actually working. What am I missing? ... or what's different in a FastCGI environment?

Comment: Is this for a windows machine?

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution?

Comment: nope. only interesting case where someone uses fcgi is on nginx. the rest are probably cheap shared hosts which I don't care much about. maybe looking into some common platforms like wordpress could give some hint...?